# Sort Numeric & Alphanumeric Accordingly in PHP MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting

I am using a Query which sorts like;

```
1
2
3A
3
4A
4
```

But I want to get it

```
1
2
3
3A
4
4A
```

What I am using is

```
SELECT * FROM `sections` ORDER BY CAST(`act` as DECIMAL) ASC
```

What I exactly want is First Number then Alphanumeric

```
3 then 3A
```

Comment: Otherfield ?? Otherfield will be written same or again act

Comment: Yes it is Only 1 Column

Comment: It's called natural sorting, mysql does not support this type of sorting, you can use php's `natsort()` to achieve that.

Comment: what is the datatype for `act` anyway? normal order by works fine http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50fb55/1

Comment: the datatype is `varchar` for `act` because some time it has only numeric and some time alphanumeric

Comment: Normal sorting does not go Good. Normal Order makes 3, 3A correct but other sorting goes random

Comment: Normal Sorting Makes 3, 3A, 3B Correct but Distrurbs the other.
See Image
https://prnt.sc/v21175

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you'll always have integer first and then characters in your `acts` column. Normally this is called `Natural Sorting`.

**Problem Understanding:**

- Normal sorting works perfectly when we're dealing with variations of a single number i.e. `1, 1A, 1B, 1AB..`.
- Due to string type, it fails when we sort between numbers which starts with same digit like `1, 10, 100...`.

We can sort in following manner.

- First sort them based on their integer values.
- Then sort them normally which mysql takes care by default.

```
SELECT * FROM sections
ORDER BY CAST(acts AS UNSIGNED), acts
```

Check corresponding [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bzwMANB5hpRMqSRZ8ej1sJ/0). It is working for MySQL `5.5, 5.6, 5.7 & 8.0`.