# ORDER BY SQL QUERY in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a table Called Lot# in my database. I used "Order by" to sort from smallest to largest. But it only counts the first digit of the number. I even used "ASC".

```
Ex...
------------
| Lot #    |
------------
|    1     |
|   10     |
|   11     |
|   12     |
|    2     | 
|    3     |
|    4     |
|    5     |
|    6     |
|    7     |
|    8     |
|    9     |
------------
```

Comment: That's text ordering, is your DB field a string (nchar, nvarchar, whatever) instead of a number (integer)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort Numeric & Alphanumeric Accordingly in PHP MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64420770/sort-numeric-alphanumeric-accordingly-in-php-mysql)

Comment: its varchar datatype in my database

Answer (score 0):

Strongly recommend to convert datatype of column to `Integer` as suggested by @Gusman.

If that is not possile then you can type cast for sorting purpose.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Lot
ORDER BY CAST(column_name AS UNSIGNED)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without converting, you can also sort the data using the following code:

```
select * from Lot order by len(column_name), column_name
```